# What is difference between these two cron jobs?

Tags: php, cron, lamp

I am very new to php, if anyone can help me by telling what the difference is between these two cron commands, I would be very thankful:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/delightl/public_html/myfolder/run.php
```

and

```
php -q /home/delightl/public_html/myfolder/run.php
```

I am totally confused.. On my GoDaddy server, the second command worked, but in another resellerclub server both worked. What is difference between these commands?

Comment: Think for the 'php' command as "shortcut" to '/usr/local/bin/php'
At 1 server you can use both but on other the full path can be different.. Then only 'php' will work ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is that one specifies the full path to the PHP binary, and the other doesn't.

PHP can be installed in different locations.  That's why it works on one server, and not the other.

Comment: No, only if the environment that's being used for executing the cronjob has the php command in it's path.

Comment: Nope, as Sven said it is not gonna work if that condition is met...the same for /usr/local/bin/php -q because php can be installed in a different path

Comment: @user3302488 No, there isn't.  You either need to know where the binary is installed, or have it in your path.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pro and a con to using either of these:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/delightl/public_html/myfolder/run.php
```

**Pro:** Specifies the full path to the PHP binary, does not depend on the user's `$PATH` environment variable to correctly include the path to where PHP is installed.
**Con:** The location of the PHP binary can vary from system to system.

```
php -q /home/delightl/public_html/myfolder/run.php
```

**Pro:** *Usually* does not require alteration from system to system.
**Con:** Will frequently not work as many PHP packages will not add PHP to the `$PATH` of the cron user, or the environment in which cron is run is left blank or not populated because it is not an interactive session.

IMHO the best solution is to always use the full path. If you are not certain what the path is run `which php` via shell which will tell you the full path to the binary, so long as it is in *your* `$PATH`.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29